# How to get the index values of two in level sec to subtract A & B using iloc

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

How to get the index values of two in level sec to subtract A & B for every level in first

```
bar  two     -0.673690  0.113648


 first  sec      A         B
bar     one     -0.424972  0.567020  
        two     -0.673690  0.113648 
baz     one      0.404705  0.577046 
        two     -0.370647 -1.157892 
foo     one      1.075770 -0.109050  
        two      0.357021 -0.674600 
qux     one     -1.294524  0.413738 
        two     -0.013960 -0.362543`
```

Comment: Please provide the data that created this frame, or else it's too much work to create it again.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: the above data can be found in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

Comment: @technical - Sure, but what need output? position of `bar, two` ? Or row? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I think need select by `loc` with `tuple`, for return one row `DataFrame` add `[]`:

```
df = df.loc[[('bar','two')]]
print (df)
                 A         B
first sec                   
bar   two -0.67369  0.113648
```

Or for `Series`:

```
s = df.loc[('bar','two')]
#alternative
#s = df.xs(('bar','two'))
print (s)
A    -0.67369
B    0.113648
Name: (bar, two), dtype: object
```

But if need position by `tuple` use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
i = df.index.get_loc(('bar','two'))
print (i)
1
```